# UICollectionViewController not showing subviews of custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I intend to make an overview of products using custom cells in a collectionview. I have set everything up, I get no errors, but somehow the contents of the cell dont' get shown.

I have

- created a subclass of UICollectionViewCell
- added all subviews in storyboard and connected them as IBOutlets to my class
- registered the custom cell using `self.collectionView!.registerClass(ProductCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)`
- checked the datasource, no errors there. here's numberOfItemsInSection:

```m
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var items: Int = 0
        if (section == 0) {
            if (currentCategory == nil) {
                items = sharedStore.categories.count
            } else {
                items = currentCategory.categories.count
            }
        } else if (section == 1) {
            if (currentCategory == nil) {
                items = sharedStore.products.count
            } else {
                items = currentCategory.items.count
            }
        }
        return items
    }
```

- set up the cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```m
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        //initialize shit
        cell.titleLabel = UILabel()
        cell.priceLabel = UILabel()

        if(indexPath.section == 0) {
            let current: Category!

            //get model object
            if(currentCategory == nil) {
                if(sharedStore.categories.count > 0) {
                    current = sharedStore.categories[indexPath.row] as! Category
                } else {
                    current = nil
                }
            } else {
                if(currentCategory.categories.count > 0 ) {
                    current = currentCategory.categories[indexPath.row] as! Category
                } else {
                    current = nil
                }
            }

            cell.itemImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "folderImage.png"))
            cell.itemImage.hidden = false
            cell.titleLabel.text = current.title as String
            cell.priceLabel.hidden = true
        }
 return cell
 }
```

The cell is empty. No image, no title, and no pricelabel.
I know the datasource is working properly, because when I add a product, it shows a new cell.

Any suggestions on how I can get my items in the cell?

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Where do you return cell? Can you please post more code (especially numberOfItemsInSection)

Comment: thanks, return must have missed out when copying the code. I also added numberOfItemsInSection.

Comment: So far so good. What about numberOfSectionsInCollectionView? Also did you set delegate to your collection view?

Comment: it basically returns 2, hard coded that one. I don't suspect any problems in the data source as the view responds as it should. If I add a product, It shows a new cell. My problem is that the cell doesn't show any subviews. The cell itself gets displayed properly. Maybe something in the setup of the cell?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I figured it out: For some reason, when you add subviews to a custom UICollectionViewcell in a storyboard, it doesn't automatically add them to the cell when you run it. Therefore, you'll have to do `cell.addSubview(subview)`for all properties of that cell, ether in the custom cell class or in the cellForItemAtIndex.

Comment: 1. If your using a storyboard set identifier in that and you need do nothing but dequeue using said identifier 2. If your using xib use registerNib... 3. All your problems stem from using registerClass incorrectly.

Comment: I cannot confirm this for iOS 9: `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` established subview relationships as visible in the storyboard and hence as expected.